# requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.dev.shadow.funnel-fuel.comuser', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:

Tags: python, timeout

I am a beginner in Python. I have this code for my Autotests:
Device: MacOS m2

```
def test_get_user_active_list():
    params = {'filter': '{"createdAt":{"gte":"2023-08-31T21:00:00.000Z","lte": "2023-10-31T21:00:00.000Z"}}',
              'range': '2'}
    res = get(f'user/active-list/{params}')
```

And method get describe here:

```
def get(endpoint, params=None):
    response = requests.get(
        URL + endpoint,
        params,
        timeout=0.5
    )
    assert response.status_code == 200
    return response.json()
```

I get this error:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='***', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /active-list/%7B'filter':%20'%7B%22createdAt%22:%7B%22gte%22:%222023-08-31T21:00:00.000Z%22,%22lte%22:%20%222023-10-31T21:00:00.000Z%22%7D%7D',%20'range':%20'2'%7D (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x106ee35d0>: Failed to resolve 'api.dev.shadow.funnel-fuel.comuser' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)"))
```

I tried this

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=1)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)

session.get(url)
```

and this

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=3)
```

and I get this error anywhere.

Comment: I found issue in URL, it missed one '/'  in line "user/active-list/"